# Add a user to a domain group and set the user privileges to certain folder Win10

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

I have a user in my workplace domain, I want to add him to a specific domain group then assign him some privileges on a specific folder. I wonder how this can be done using command line or a more automated process than doing it step by step as I do this quite often. I'm using AD on windows 10

Looks like [`dsmod group`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732423(v=ws.10)) can be used but I don't know how. Like if I have a user with username `userh01` in domain `mydom` how I can add him automatically to group `mydomgroup1`?

I've tried this command `dsmod group "mydomgroup1" -addmbr "userh01"` but I get this error `dsmod failed:Value for 'Target object for this command' has incorrect format.` Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ActiveDirectory Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) for PowerShell and the [Add-ADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) cmdlet

example: `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity MyGroup -Members MyUser`